# OpenGL opening Mesh (.m) file with Visual Studio2010

Tags: c++, opengl, mesh

For some reason, it just won't load the mesh file. I can't tell if its because Im entering something wrong, or if I just dont have the file in the right folder. I have it in the same folder as the .exe right now, and I have it under my "source files" too (that could be wrong).

**Mesh.cpp**

```
#include "MeshTable.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

void MeshTable::ReadMesh_M(const char *filename) {
    points.clear();
    faces.clear();

    //the Vertex id in .m file begins from 1,
    //we insert an empty point to align the index
    points.push_back(Point());

    std::ifstream input("C:\\Users\\Zach\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\MAIN\\Release\\dog.m");
    while(input.good()) {
        std::string line;
        getline(input, line);

        if (line.empty()) {     
        continue;       
    }

    std::stringstream ss(line);
    std::string title;
    int id;
    ss >> title;

    if (title == "Vertex") {
        Point pt;
        ss >> id >> pt[0] >> pt[1] >> pt[2];
        points.push_back(pt);
    } 
    else if (title == "Face") {
        Face face;
        ss >> id >> face.pt_ids[0] >> face.pt_ids[1] >> face.pt_ids[2];
        faces.push_back(face);
    }

}
input.close();
}

void MeshTable::SaveMesh_M(const char *filename) {
std:: ofstream output(C:\\Users\\Zach\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\MAIN\\Release\\dog_out.m);
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < points.size(); ++i) {
    const Point& pt = points[i];
    output << "Vertex " << i << " " << pt[0] << " " << pt[1] << " " << pt[2] << "\n";
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
    const Face& face = faces[i];
    output << "Face " << i + 1 << " " << face.pt_ids[0] << " " << face.pt_ids[1] << " " << face.pt_ids[2] << "\n";
}
output.close();
}
```

It builds fine, but when I try to debug it, the OpenGL window pops open for like 3 seconds and then closes and says "The program '[3188] Main.exe: Native' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff)." Which comes from my main.cpp.

```
if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Load a .m file as a mesh table.\n";
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input_mesh.m\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

**EDIT** Once I deleted this, it worked. My teacher gave me this (part) of the code so I dont really understand why that would make it not work.

```
if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Load a .m file as a mesh table.\n";
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input_mesh.m\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: There. Only put the mesh loader

Comment: Do you get the same error if you comment out the `render_mesh`?

Comment: Well when I deleted 

    if (argc != 2) {
  std::cout << "Load a .m file as a mesh table.\n";
  std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input_mesh.m\n";
  exit(-1);
     }

it worked, dont know why my teacher would put that in there when it makes the whole thing not work...

Comment: @NicolBolas FYI : link is broken : *removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation* (at least for peeps < 10k)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (argc != 2) {
    std::cout << "Load a .m file as a mesh table.\n";
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " input_mesh.m\n";
    exit(-1);
}
```

You need to pass name of mesh file into command line parameter when you run the program. I.e. it should be launched as "program.exe meshfile.m".

In VS 2008 debugging parameters/command line arguments could be specified in project properties->configuration properties->debugging->command arguments. In VS2010 they could be in similar locations.

Also, read "output" when you run the program. Code fragment provided by your teacher actually prints program usage.